# C# Screen resolution and Form display

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# WinForms application and when I give the executable to different users the application displays in different sizes (based on their screen resolution). Some of the parts of the application can't be seen.

Is there anyway to auto-size the window based on the screen resolution, or is there another approach?

**EDIT :** furthermore it appears in different styles under different Operating systems, is there away to standardize its design ?

Comment: One thing I'd like to say is, if it is possible, use WPF. WPF applications are resolution independent, so an inch is an inch is an inch, regardless of monitor resolution or monitor DPI.

Comment: The different styles, if you are referring to scrollbars, etc, are just how each operating system displays those objects.  In Winforms, you have no practical way of changing this-- just live with it or go to WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Control.ScaleControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.scalecontrol.aspx) and [Control.Scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158413.aspx)

```
private void MainForm_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    float width_ratio = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 1280);
    float heigh_ratio = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 800f);

    SizeF scale = new SizeF(width_ratio, heigh_ratio);

    this.Scale(scale);

   //And for font size
   foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
   {
      control.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", c.Font.SizeInPoints * heigh_ratio * width_ratio);
   }
}
```

In the case when the development platform resolution is 1280x800

According to  @sixlettervariables 's answer **Docking and anchoring** will help of course.

Comment: How do i use it? is there any sample code where i could look at ?

Comment: @Navid Rahmani , Your way it only maintains the form size, but the buttons and links inside the form hasn't got re-sized :(

Comment: No `Control.Scale` scales all content

Comment: If you mean the font size check my answer again

Comment: Actually i am displaying a browser on the Form, so i need to resize the controls of the browser as well. How should i do this ?

Comment: @Navid My form has a few panels, and on that panels there are several textboxes, buttons and links buttons. I have placed these panels infront of a Webbroswer Controller. So when i am gonna resize the application i have to consider these facts as well. any clue ?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have specified your controls with absolute positioning and other layout defaults. In order to make a WinForms application that looks and feels the same and behaves correctly in various resizing scenarios, you need to utilize the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) and [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) properties. Arranging controls in WinForms can be a tiring process, but MSDN includes some nice [How To's on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty26a068.aspx).

I would also suggest following along with this [TechRepublic article, which covers the difference between Anchoring and Docking](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908), and shows you visually what each property accomplishes:

[image: Anchoring example from the TechRepublic Article]

Comment: So do i have to re-design my application according to this? isn't there any other way to handle this issue :(

Comment: @illep: unfortunately, these are the properties which govern the layout of controls during resizing. @Navid's answer covers a workaround for the interesting side effect of DPI changes. Basically, your program should be liberal in the resolutions/DPI it supports. I was certainly frustrated the first time I realized just how much effort was required to make my GUI look/feel/behave the same across computers. You're not alone!

Comment: Actually i am displaying a browser on the Form, so i need to resize the controls of the browser as well. How should i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
private void MainForm_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) 
  { 
     this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size 
  }
```