# How I can get screen orientation?

Tags: c#, screen-orientation

I'm entering number of screen on which I want to show the form. And I must get screen orientation. Does anybody know how to do that?

```
 public UIManager(int screenIndex)
    {
        this.ScreenIndex = screenIndex;            

        try
        {
            Screen[] all_screens;
            all_screens = Screen.AllScreens;

            if (all_screens.Length >= ScreenIndex)
            {
                this.customer_form.Left = all_screens[this.ScreenIndex].Bounds.Width;
                this.customer_form.Top = all_screens[this.ScreenIndex].Bounds.Height;                    
                this.customer_form.Show();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you mean portrait vs landscape? In that case look at which is the larger dimension. But remember there are square screens out there as well…

Comment: If I'm not wrong you need to P/Invoke [EnumDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use `dmDisplayOrientation` of [DEVMODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Why not just use [`SystemInformation.SceenOrientation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.screenorientation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/6510861/3225

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the value from the `Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation` [class](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation), returned by `DisplayInformation.getForCurrentView()` and its `currentOrientation` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayorientations.aspx):

```
 DisplayOrientations currentOrientation = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.CurrentOrientation;
```

From the official doc:
[image: DisplayOrientations enumeration]

Comment: @Pepinho I suspect you might be missing a referenced DLL, consult the API documentation.