# C# Get Screen Orientation

Tags: c#, screen-orientation

How to find the current screen orientation using C#?

I have tried the following code without much success.

```
DisplayOrientations currentOrientation = 
Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.CurrentOrientation;
```

Comment: Check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.screenorientation(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what is the value in "currentOrientation" variable, after you execute the above code? Reference this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604933/how-i-can-get-screen-orientation

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604933/how-i-can-get-screen-orientation)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got the answer from the below post,        ----------------                         

var orientation = SystemInformation.ScreenOrientation;
Console.WriteLine(orientation);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the [SystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation(v=vs.110).aspx)-object instead and take its `ScreenOrientation`.

You will get a [ScreenOrientation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screenorientation(v=vs.110).aspx)-enumeration back.

```
var orientation = SystemInformation.ScreenOrientation;
Console.WriteLine(orientation);
```

Prints 'Angle0' on my system with default orientation

Comment: Works perfectly , Thanks a lot for the quick response.